# Exchange 2010 w/ CAS + Edge Transport. Make CAS Internet Facing?

Tags: cas

If I'm deploying an Edge Transport Server to the DMZ, do I need to make the Client Access Server internet facing in order to send / receive mail from the WAN?

Asked another way: If I deploy an Edge Transport server with the CAS in the internal network, and if the CAS is not internet facing, will email flow between WAN and CAS?